# Save iframe content using Powershell

Tags: html, powershell, web-scraping, iframe

With below code I'm trying to save 1st `iframe` content using Powershell but saved file is empty. Any help will be appreciated. Below is not actual site.
Actually I've to extract some content from table available in 1st frame and use that data in excel vba. But since vba has also issue, some error, trying get data using `Powershell`.

```
$url="https://example.com"
$ie         = New-Object -com InternetExplorer.Application
$ie.Navigate($url)
$ie.visible = $true

Start-Sleep -s 20
$ie.document.body.innerHtml >> "d:\temp\output.html"     # This gives 5 iframe list
$p = ($ie.document.getElementsByTagName("iframe"))[0]    # Getting the 1st Frame
$q = $p.contentWindow.document                           # referncing the document within the frame
$q.documentElement.innerhtml >> "d:\temp\output.html"
$ie.contentWindow.document.documentElement.innerhtml >> "d:\temp\output.html"
$ie.Stop()
$ie.Quit()
```

Comment: `while ($ie.busy -eq $True) {   Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 5000 }` is no safe way to wait until a website has been completely loaded. There are different methods, but none of them work in all cases. It might be that your iframe is still not there. To investigate on that, just replace your loop by a fixed wait of 5 seconds and check if you get an iframe.

Comment: I cannot paste actual site as it won't open in public.

Comment: Replaced above line with `Start-Sleep -s 10` still same result.

Comment: Do you see the iframe, when PS opens the visible IE tab? If so, do you see your iframe in the output of `$ie.document.body.innerHtml`?

Comment: Yes, WIth `$ie.document.body.innerHtml` I get total 5 frames and 1st that I'm interested in is: `<frame name="displayFrame" src="/webpr/webpr.php?objtype=view&amp;g_userid=a3rgcw&amp;g_session_id=26288865&amp;g_devmode=&amp;g_dbname=&amp;g_prid=7429387">`

Comment: Well, the tag name here is not `iframe`, but `frame`. So you should look for that.

Comment: It worked, Thomas. Thanks a lot!